# How to redirect Multisite subdomains to a 404 page when accessing wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

How to restrict wp-admin page to subdomains? We have multi domains in a WordPress site and I need to redirect `subdomain.websitename.php/wp-admin/` to a 404 page.

For this, I used this code but it's not redirecting.

```
# wp-admin 404 for subdomains

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?websitename.com/wp-admin/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.websitename.com/wp-admin/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.htm [L]
```

Comment: Can you give more context on why do you need this? Maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: actually we have multiple subdomains in wordpress. each user have one subdomain. super admin can access wp-admin. (like website.com/wp-admin) but subdomain.website.com/wp-admin redirect to 404 page. for this how to write htaccess. thanks

Comment: My doubt: is this going to happen to every user? Or only regular users? Can super admin access subdomain/wp-admin?

Comment: superuser has website.com/wp-admin.admin can access this . but subdomain.website.com/wp-admin nobody can access this url even super admin also

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Must Use plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), where we will hook into `admin_head` and check for a specific user (I believe at least *one person* should be able to administer the sites, right?) and if it is a sub-site or not.

If the conditions are not met, do the redirection:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Block Access to Sub-sites WP-Admin
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16363207/1287812
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 */

add_action( 'admin_head', 'b5f_prevent_multisite_wp_admin' );

function b5f_prevent_multisite_wp_admin() 
{
    // Allow access only to one user, adjust the ID bellow
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();  
    if ( 2 == $current_user->ID ) 
        return;

    // Allow access only to main site WP-Admin
    if( is_main_site() )
        return;

    // User not allowed and site is a sub-site
    // Redirect to front page of current site
    wp_redirect( site_url() );
    die();
}
```

Check the documentation for the functions [`site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [`network_site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_site_url) to adjust your redirection to a specific page (from the subdomain or from the main site).

Comment: i installed this plugin actually in subdomains current userid not displaying. it is not working for me. is there any chance to restrict from htaccess. may be i am guessing have to change these lines in .htaccess............RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct user ID? What if you remove the user check? Sorry, I'm not good with Rewrite Rules...

Comment: when ever admin login this function calling but using subdomain user login this function is not calling. it is redirecting to wp admin panel after login

Comment: if we login from subdomain.website.com/wp-admin then it is not calling b5f_prevent_multisite_wp_admin(). if we login from website.com/wp-admin then only it is caling b5f_prevent_multisite_wp_admin(). so how can i restrict subdomain users.